# How to clean/clear cache of a SubjectReplay instance in rxjs?

Tags: stream, rxjs

I have a SubjectReplay and I would like to reset it to no cache values so after this reset the next subscriber doesn't get the history?

Example

- new subject replay
- subject.next(1)
- reset subject <- this question
- subject.subscribe() // should NOT receive 1

how can I do this? I need the subject to be the same instance.

Comment: Do you mean a ReplaySubject? There is no method in its API to reset it, once it has a value it will always emit the last value when subscribed to.

Comment: It will emit all previous values. Yeah I noticed it doesn't have an API to reset, but I was wondering what are the alternatives for this case scenario? thanks

Comment: You're right; I usually use `ReplaySubject(1)` which only replays the last value but in the general case it may emit all previous values.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at using a combination of special values and `filter` operator to get something close to what you are trying to achieve.

Let's make a simple case.

You want to replay just the last value and `null` is the special value representing the reset. The code would be

```
const rs = new ReplaySubject<any>(1); // replay the last value
const rsObs = rs.asObservable().pipe(filter(d => d !== null));
rs.next(1);
rs.next(2);

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('first subscription');
    rsObs.subscribe(console.log)  // logs 2 on the console
}, 10);


setTimeout(() => {
    rs.next(null);
}, 20);


setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('second subscription');
    rsObs.subscribe(console.log)  // nothing is logged
}, 30);
```

Comment: This will fail both for ReplaySubjects using anything other than a retention of '1` and for observables that require being able to emit `null`.

Comment: @IngoBürk you are right, it is just an idea that may work under strict conditions. If you have to emit null, then you have to find another way to communicate that there is a reset request. If retention is > 1 then things get more complex. It is a simple idea which can work in simple cases

Comment: Well, but OP had already clarified in the comments that they're using an infinite retention.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that comes to my mind with your requirement

> I need the subject to be the same instance

would be to have the following observables:

```js
// This is your input
const source$: Observable<T>;

const proxy$ = new ReplaySubject<T>(n);
const reset$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
```

Now it's important that we hook up the following before you emit on `source$`:

```
source$.pipe(timestamp()).subscribe(proxy$);
```

Then, finally, you can expose your data like this:

```js
const data$ = proxy$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(reset$),
  filter(([timedItem, resetTimestamp]) => timedItem.timestamp > resetTimestamp),
  map(([timedItem]) => timedItem.value),
);
```

You can now use `reset$.next(+new Date())` to trigger the reset.

---

If you can make sure to provide timestamped values to `source$`, you can skip the `proxy$`.

Comment: ... Although implementing your own observable class might be easier and make for a prettier API. If I have time later I'll update my answer.