# Is there an RxJava Subject that caches values and forgets them once emitted?

Tags: rx-java2

I am looking for a `Subject` type (or some combination of operators) that would achieve a certain behaviour.

- A `Subject` is created
- A `Subject`'s `onNext()` is called multiple times, all those values are cached in that `Subject`
- A `Consumer` subscribes to that `Subject`
- The `Consumer` receives all the values that have been cached
- The `Consumer` unsubscribes from the `Subject` .. through a call to `dispose()`
- A `Subject`'s `onNext()` is called with 2 new values
- A `Consumer` subscribes to that `Subject`
- The `Consumer` should only receive the 2 new values, because the old values have already been emitted.

What I need basically is a special case between a `ReplaySubject` and a `BehaviourSubject`.

`ReplaySubject` replays all events .. `BehaviourSubject` replays on the last event.

I want a `Subject` that replays only events that has not been consumed. In other words .. events that the `Subject` had no subscribers when they emitted.

For completion, here's a test case that clarifies the behaviour

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Subject<String> subject = MyDesiredSubject.create();

    subject.onNext("1");
    subject.onNext("2");

    TestObserver<String> testObserver = subject.test();
    testObserver.assertValues("1", "2");
    testObserver.dispose();

    subject.onNext("3");
    subject.onNext("4");
    testObserver = subject.test();
    testObserver.assertValues("3", "4");
}
```

Comment: I think all your are looking is for a way to clear history, and this answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996348/how-to-clean-clear-cache-of-a-subjectreplay-instance-in-rxjs

Answer (score 2):

You could use `DispatchWorkSubject` in https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions .

> A Subject variant that buffers items and allows one or more Observers
>   to exclusively consume one of the items in the buffer asynchronously.
>   If there are no Observers (or they all disposed), the
>   DispatchWorkSubject will keep buffering and later Observers can resume
>   the consumption of the buffer.

But if you only want to support a maximum of **1** subscriber at a time, then `UnicastWorkSubject` (also in Rx2 extensions).

Comment: `UnicastSubject`, `UnicastWorkSubject` and `DispatchWorkSubject` has a problem with specify buffer size. In `create()` method you can pass `capacityHint` which isn't a specify capacity size. It's just a hint because of the implementation of `SpscLinkedArrayQueue` and `SpmcLinkedArrayQueue`